# Quali sono le implicazioni di «chi sa come ha divorato» in un contesto da Pirandello?

Tags: meaning, sentences

Ho una domanda su un passaggio nel romanzo di Luigi Pirandello, *Il fu Mattia Pascal*. Nel [capitolo 7](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Il_fu_Mattia_Pascal/7), «Cambio treno»:

> Alla prima stazione italiana comprai un giornale, con la speranza che mi facesse addormentare. Lo spiegai, e al lume del lampadino elettrico, mi misi a leggere. Ebbi così la consolazione di sapere che il castello di Valencay, messo all’incanto per la seconda volta, era stato aggiudicato al signor conte De Castellane per la somma di due milioni e trecento mila franchi. La tenuta attorno al castello era di duemila ottocento ettari: la più vasta di Francia.
>
> — Press’a poco, come la *Stìa*... »
>
> Lessi che l’imperatore di Germania aveva ricevuto a Potsdam, a mezzodì, l’ambasciata marocchina, e che al ricevimento aveva assistito il segretario di Stato, barone de Richtofen. La missione, presentata poi all’imperatrice, era stata trattenuta a colazione, e **chi sa come aveva divorato**!

Chi ha divorato? Che cosa è stata divorata? Cosa vuol dire la parola *come*? Ho letto dapprima come *chi sa **quanto** aveva divorato (= mangiato nel modo troppo bestiale)*, nel senso della gelosia per il modo di vivere dei politici, ma non ne sono sicuro. Qual è la logica del passaggio? I marocchini sono stati tanto affamati? Non suona convincente... Ho anche pensato che potrebbe essere l'imperatrice della frase precedente il pretesto per quell'osservazione, ma non riesco a capire in qual modo...

Insomma, vorrei chiedervi, se non vi dispiace: qual è il ruolo di questa frase nel discorso, cosa vuol dire, che cosa implica? Tante grazie!

Comment: Il soggetto di "aveva divorato" è "la missione", cioè, "l'ambasciata marocchina". Il testo spiega che i marocchini erano stati invitati a colazione, l'io narrante immagina che, come tu hai detto, abbiano mangiato in "modo troppo bestiale" e fa questa domanda in modo ironico.

Comment: @Charo Grazie! Cioè l'osservazione è un po' discriminatoria per i marocchini, per i modi moderni, e non gelosa verso la corte della Germania come ho pensato dapprima, se ti ho capito bene.

Comment: Penso sia proprio così, @Evgeniy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il passaggio direi che significa proprio quello che hai inteso tu, cioè mangiare in modo ingordo, assumendo un comportamento simile agli animali:

> **[divorare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/divorare/)** v. tr. [dal lat. *devŏrare*, comp. di *de-* e *vorare*
>   «inghiottire»] (*io divóro*, ecc.). – 1. Mangiare con ingordigia, detto
>   propr. degli animali, spec. feroci: *il leone divorò la preda; ella fu
>   prestamente divorata da molti lupi (Boccaccio)*; per estens., riferito
>   a persona (come soggetto), mangiare avidamente o in gran fretta:
>   *divorò la sua cena ed uscì; si scagliò contro il malcapitato come se
>   volesse divorarlo.*

A margine di questo ti segnalo [questa scheda](https://www.edatlas.it/documents/68dcbfce-5917-4070-b736-1d49e2004864) riguardante il passaggio da te citato, con alcuni spunti di analisi che possono aiutarti a capire meglio il testo.

Comment: Cioè sono stati i marocchini ad essere i "divoratori" insieme alla famiglia imperiale tedesca e alla corte tedesca? Oppure soltanto i marocchini, mentre la famiglia imperiale mangiava come la gente normale? Credo che sia questo che dovessi credere dapprima. :) Grazie!

Comment: L'imperatrice aveva offerto la colazione alla delegazione marocchina e loro avevano onorato l'invito mangiando in modo quasi animalesco. Sicuramente non erano abituati alla corte e non seguivano il protocollo alla lettera.

Comment: Ho capito, merci!

Comment: "Credo che sia questo che dovessi credere dapprima" => intendevo di dire "chiedere"... però va bene anche così.